# How can I renew lease when it kept printing eth0 lease expired x seconds ago?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, vmware

My guest VM cannot get an IP address from my host.

It keeps printing:

```
eth0: lease expired x seconds ago
```

I've tried to start `dhclient -r` and `dhclient` and restart eth0 to no avail, see [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-renew-dhcp-client-ip-address/) for more.

How can I get a new lease in my guest?

Comment: This is probably very distro dependent.  Have you set the host VMware to actually do networking with a DHCP server?

Comment: Yes. The problem is also I can have a new lease but only when I restart the host dhcp server from vmware? When I restart eth0 or dhclient in the guest nothing happens. Currently when I want to connect to the network I need to manually restart host dhcp everytime I start my day. It's annoying routine I want to avoid.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the DHCP server is running? The protocol says that before the lease runs out, the leasee asks for renewal. Or try setting the lease to permanent (fixed IP for the given MAC).